# React Native: Illegal node ID set as an input for Animated.Add node

Tags: android, react-native, autofocus, react-native-textinput

I'm using React Native `0.63.4` and getting this error sometimes. Pretty sure it is related to input focus, both `autofocus` and user manual focus. The problem is: it almost never happens, very sporadic, but crashes the app in both RELEASE and DEBUG, and I barely know where to look for it. I've found some articles talking about a similar error, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551914/custom-header-throwing-a-illegal-node-id-set-as-an-input-for-animated-diffclamp) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12732), but still don't help. I also found this [link](https://vimsky.com/zh-tw/examples/detail/java-class-com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationCausedNativeException.html) which shows some conditions that might lead to the exception. I noticed it happening, in my cases, to `Animated.Add` and `Animated.Multiply`.
Does anybody have any idea what's going on? Thanks.

[image]